how to choose the optimum discharge resistor?
I was wondering how to choose the value of the dicharging resistor in the figure below:

The figure comes from : Figure link
SPECIFICATIONS:
I'm building a system with fast-switching transistor-based transistors and during testing the power supply sometimes drops its voltage to 1-2 volts, so I decided to put a 2.2mF capacitor in parallel next to the power supply and that seems to work. However, I have a few questions now:
As the 2.2mF added is a large value of C, it takes longer to discharge when the system is switched off, which can lead to safety problems. I therefore want to add a parallel resistor to dissipate the power, so that when the power supply is switched off, this resistor dissipates the charges stored by capacitor C1, as shown in the figure above.
CLARIFYING THE CIRCUIT:
The circuit I want to set up is just formed by the discharge resistor and C1, nothing more (there's no R1 or diode) and the voltage can vary from 5 to 9 volts.
QUESTION
My question is how to correctly choose the value of this resistor without interfering with the main circuit after this section. I wanted to put a parallel resistor of 0.1-1 ohm/5Watts but I don't really know what kind of problems I'm about to encounter.

I know you are asking about how to size the resistor. And you provide a very low valued suggestion. Seems to me that $1:\tau$ gets you more than 63% voltage reduction and dissipation of 85% of the stored energy. If you do that in less than a minute, wouldn't that be good enough? Tell me again why you need this to be so fast?

I just want to discharge the capacitor when the psu is turned down. I dont need it to be fast what is fast is the circuit that is put next this stage, du to the switching it makes the psu drop its voltage.

Then even a 5-10 k resistor might be fine and you could avoid the diode as well, linking the two resistors in series for discharge. The diode is really helpful when you need a quick discharge path. But you don't need that.

Working from your words, rather than your schematic which the question disowns, it sounds like you need to discharge a 2.2 mF capacitor in some time t. 'Fully' discharged is usually deemed to be 5 or more RC time constants, unless there's some proper specification on the actual final voltage.
A 1 k resistor will give you 2.2 s time constant, or about 10 seconds to discharge. Similarly 100 Ω for a 1 second discharge, and 10 Ω for 100 ms. How fast do you need it discharged?
The resistor appears to be in parallel with your power supply. As long as the PSU can supply the required current, and the resistor can dissipate the power, it won't interfere with the rest of the circuit.
The 0.1 to 1 Ω resistor values you are suggesting would dissipate 50 W and 5 W respectively, but would discharge the capacitor in 1 ms and 10 ms. That's rather a lot of power to waste on a board, and the resistor will get very hot.

I dont need it to be avery fast discharge, as long as it discharge after a while when the psu is turned down is fine for me (i just dont want to put everything on a pcb and then because of a bad contact the board burns du to the stored charge in the capacitor). That said, a 1k sounds good to me.

The only sane thing to do is conducting a risk analysis according to your specific application. The risk analysis tells you how fast and to what level the capacitor needs to be discharged.
It might take 5 minutes after removing power for any live circuits to become touchable, because that's the time it takes to disassemble a protective housing, for example. So it might be ok to pick a discharge resistor that discharges the capacitor to a safe level in a couple of seconds.
What's considered a safe level again depends on your application.
If the discharge resistor happens to become so low in value that power dissipation becomes an issue during normal operation, I personally try to use a SPDT switch to remove the power: During normal operation, the discharge resistor is disconnected and doesn't waste energy. When the SPDT switch removes the power, it also connects the discharge resistor at the same time.
